# How do I remove certain coefficients from a C++ Eigen array, given a boolean vector?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a `Eigen::VectorXd v` and I would like to create another vector `w` containing only the coefficients from `v` meeting a certain criteria, like positiveness, something like

```
Eigen::VectorXd v(3);
v << -1, 0, 1;
w = v(v > 0);
std:: cout << v; // prints  -1, 0, 1
std:: cout << w; // prints 1
```

How can I do this in Eigen?

Answer (score 0):

Copy `v` in `w`, sort `w` with `std::sort` and then find the first non-positive value with `std::find_if`.  That will be the end of your list of conforming values.

You can use any other criteria with `std::sort`.

Answer (score -1):

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
void push_back(VectorXd &v, T val, T ref)
{
    if (val > ref /*Or Your condition*/) {
        v.conservativeResize(v.size() + 1);
        v[v.size() - 1] = val;
    }
}

int main()
{
    VectorXd v(3); 
    v << 1, 2, 3; 

    const double ref = 0.0f;
    push_back(v, 4.0, ref);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v(i) << "  ";
    return 0;
}
```

You get the idea, you can even templatize the first argument.

Comment: I don't see how this will solve the problem, if `v` had a negative number, how would this code remove it?  *edit*: I guess you mean I have to loop over all elements of v and add only those meeting the criteria in w?